# A better way to delete the data in a MongoDB collection but keeping the index

Tags: mongodb

I was working on my unittests which for each cases the database should be reset.

Because that the indexes should be kept but the data should be cleared, what will be a faster way to do that reset?

Answer (score 2):

I am using `pymongo`, not sure if the driver will heavily impacts the performance.

There are 2 ways that come up to my mind

- Simply executes `delete_many()`
- Drop the whole collection and recreate the indexes

I found that:

- for collections containing < 25K entries, the first way is faster
- for collections containing ~ 25K entries, two ways are similar
- for collections containing < 25K entries, the second way is faster.

---

Below is my script to test and run.

```py
import time

import pymongo
from bson import ObjectId

from extutils import exec_timing_result


client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.50.33:27017/?readPreference=primary&ssl=false")


def test_drop_recreate(col):
    col.drop()
    col.create_index([("mike", pymongo.DESCENDING)])


def test_delete_many(col):
    col.delete_many({})


def main():
    db = client.get_database("_tests")

    STEP = 1000

    to_insert = []

    for count in range(0, STEP * 101, STEP):
        # Get the MongoDB collection
        col = db.get_collection("a")

        # Insert dummy data
        to_insert.extend([{"_id": ObjectId(), "mike": "ABC"} for _ in range(STEP)])
        if to_insert:
            col.insert_many(to_insert)

        # Record the execution time of dropping the databㄇse then recreate indexes of it
        _start = time.time()
        test_drop_recreate(col)
        ms_drop = time.time() - _start

        # Insert dummy data
        if to_insert:
            col.insert_many(to_insert)

        # Record the execution time of simply executes `delete_many()`
        _start = time.time()
        test_delete_many(col)
        ms_del = time.time() - _start

        if ms_drop > ms_del:
            print(f"{count},-{(ms_drop / ms_del) - 1:.2%}")
        else:
            print(f"{count},+{(ms_del / ms_drop) - 1:.2%}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After I ran this script a few times, I generated a graph to visualize the result using the output.

- (Above 0) means deletion takes longer
- (Below 0) means dropping and recreating takes longer

The value represents additional time consumed.

For example: +20 means deletion takes 20 times longer than drop & create.

[image: Comparison Chart]

Comment: The drop operation makes me to recreate all the indexes manually. Is there a simple way to save the indexes before the drop and recreate the same indexes after the drop?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to "save" all the existing indexes and recreate them after the collection drop, but there are tons of edge cases and hidden parameters to the index object. Here is my shot:

```
def convert_key_to_list_index(son_index):
    """
    Convert index SON object to a list that can be used to create the same index.
    :param SON son_index: The output of "list_indexes()":
                          SON([
                              ('v', 2),
                              ('key', SON([('timestamp', 1.0)])),
                              ('name', 'timestamp_1'),
                              ('expireAfterSeconds', 3600.0)
                          ])
    :return list: List of tuples: (field, direction) to use for pymonog function create_index
    """
    key_index_list = []
    index_key_definitions = son_index["key"]
    for field, direction in index_key_definitions.items():
        item = (field, int(direction))
        key_index_list.append(item)
    return key_index_list


def drop_and_recreate_indexes(db, collection_name):
    """
    Use list_indexes() and not index_information() to get the "key" as a SON object instead of regular dict,
    Because the SON object is an ordered dict, which the order of the key of the index are important for the
    recreation action.
    """
    son_indexes = list(db[collection_name].list_indexes())
    db[collection_name].drop()

    # Re-create the collection indexes
    for son_index in son_indexes:
        # Skip the default index for the field "_id"
        # Notice: For collection without any index except of the default "_id_" index,
        #         the collection will not be recreated (Recreate the index recreate the collection).
        if son_index['name'] == '_id_':
            continue

        recreate_index(db, collection_name, son_index)


def recreate_index(db, collection_name, son_index):
    """
    Get a SON object that represent an index from the db, and create the same index in the db.
    :param pymongo.database.Database db:
    :param str collection_name:
    :param SON son_index: The object that returned from the call to pymongo.collection.Collection.list_indexes()
    # Notice: Currently supported only these fields: ["name", "unique", "expireAfterSeconds"]
    # For more fields/options see: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html
    #  ?highlight=create_index#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index

    :return:
    """
    list_index = convert_key_to_list_index(son_index)

    # This dict is defined to send parameter if exists to the "create_index" function.
    create_index_kwargs = {}

    # "name" will always be part of the SON object that represent the index.
    create_index_kwargs["name"] = son_index.get("name")

    # "unique" may exist or not in the SON object
    unique = son_index.get("unique")
    if unique:
        create_index_kwargs["unique"] = unique

    # "expireAfterSeconds" may exist or not in the SON object
    expire_after_seconds = son_index.get("expireAfterSeconds", None)
    if expire_after_seconds:
        create_index_kwargs["expireAfterSeconds"] = expire_after_seconds

    db[collection_name].create_index(list_index, **create_index_kwargs)
```